# how to set bootstrap toogle menu as default menu?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a website, i am trying to set bootstrap toogle menu as default, as many popular website now use this. toogle menu is always display. even destopp view.`
here is my code, thanks in advance .
    
                                  
                                    
                                    
                                      
                                        Toggle navigation
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                      
                                      Brand

```
                                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                                  </ul>
                                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                              </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
                            </nav>`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi be sure to close your <nav></nav> divs. 
    Replace your code with the following 
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid"> 
       <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    ...
    </button> cont here [http://www.bootply.com/pSq7nXLcfc][1]


      [1]: http://www.bootply.com/pSq7nXLcfc
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have all these code, but i want toggle menu for all device, not only tab and mobile . Hope you understand . :)